# Azure App Service goes down when Container Registry goes down

Tags: azure, docker

I have an App Service deployed from private container registry with a specific image version and with continuous integration disabled.

Recently my app went down, because container registry was inaccessible (returned 503). But it should not even try to pull image, because no action was issued on the app (no restart, no changes to settings or container settings).

How is this possible?

Comment: while a lot of things could be going on, and it is really hard to say without seeing any details, but one thing: even when you don't change anything, every now and then App Service might switch the underlying instances due to maintenance. Meaning, a new instance comes up and will take over from an existing one

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda hard to give more details except that Activity Logs were clear. But you may be right about that instance switch.